# paw : Mutual Authentication 2 Way SSL

Tags: mutual-authentication, paw-app

Does Paw Rest Client support Mutual Authentication (2 Way SSL) ?

I could not find how to define a keystore.

Thanks.

Florent.

Comment: Paw doesn't currently support client-side SSL certificates (it's on its way though).